# can somebody tell me how to resolve this issue " library not found for -lwoa_two"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios7

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L"/Users/qingyun/Sqy/iosHistory/iOS/iOS/newSDK/newFramework/GameLive/GamePlusAPI/woa"'
ld: library not found for -lwoa_two
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Xcode 5.0-DP  test by iPhone 5    iOS 7 beta 6
 OS X 10.8.4

When i add  Third-Party Libraries in my project. then had this issue.  i don't know  why.
if somebody knows how to resolve this issue, please let me know. 
thanks for reading ..

Answer (score 1):

Go to your project directory and remove the folders Pods/ and yourProject.xcworkspace.

Run `pod install` again and reopen yourProject.xcworkspace on XCode. Things should go back to normal.